# Execution order of functions in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-execution-plan, sql-function, order-of-execution

I am aware that the execution order of MySQL is not fixed. But, I heard it usually goes like this:

1. `FROM`, including `JOIN`s
2. `WHERE`
3. `GROUP BY`
4. `HAVING`
5. `SELECT`
6. `DISTINCT`
7. `ORDER BY`
8. `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`

However, if I run functions like `COUNT()` for example (like the code below), when does it get to be executed? and how does MySQL decide the subjects that will be calculated with the function (*e.g.* What to count for `COUNT()` function)? I am confused about the **execution order** and the **target designation** of functions like `AVG()`, `SUM()`, `MAX()`, *etc.* in MySQL.

```
SELECT productvendor, count(*)
FROM products
GROUP BY productvendor
HAVING count(*) >= 9;
```

Comment: Does it much matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You sequence is not correct
select is before GROUP BY

```
FROM, including JOINs
WHERE
SELECT the row  obtained  by from and where in a temporary area for others 
        operation (and build the column alias)
DISTINCT
GROUP BY
HAVING
ORDER BY
LIMIT and OFFSET
return the final result
```

the count and the aggegation function are done on a temporary result with the select column  .. this operation produce the result filtered  by having

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't know why but many of the blog posts from here says `SELECT ` is after `GROUP BY` I am confused https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/sql-query-order-of-operations https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-execution-order-of-SQL-queries

Comment: answer  updated  .. with some suggestion  ..  if the select was performed  after  the group by  ...how is possible that group by can use the alias?