# Why does the MAX function generate the right results in a group by call

Tags: sql, mysql

I am learning SQL and have created the following dataset in MySQL:

```
Create table Departments (DepartmentID int primary key, Name text);

insert into Departments values
(1001,'SRO'),
(2001,'Drs'),
(3001,'Accounting');

Create table Employees 
(
  EmployeeID int not null, 
  DepartmentID int not null,
  ManagerID int,
  Name varchar(50) not null,
  Salary int not null,
  primary key(EmployeeID),
  foreign key (DepartmentID)
    references Departments(DepartmentID)
 );

insert into Employees values
(68319,1001,NULL,'Kayling','6000.00'),
(66928,3001,68319,'Blaze','2750.00'),
(67832,1001,68319,'Clare','2550.00'),
(65646,2001,68319,'Jonas','2957.00'),
(67858,2001,65646,'Scarlet','3100.00'),
(69062,2001,65646,'Frank','3100.00'),
(63679,2001,69062,'Sandrine','900.00'),
(64989,3001,66928,'Adelyn','1700.00'),
(65271,3001,66928,'Wade','1350.00');
```

I want to find the maximum salary for each department, researching many of the articles I saw suggested running `MAX` in this form:

```
SELECT max(Salary),DepartmentID 
FROM Employees
GROUP BY DepartmentID;
```

However, given the order of operations as described in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54392599/execution-order-of-functions-in-mysql)

```
FROM, including JOINs
WHERE
SELECT the row  obtained  by from and where in a temporary area for others 
        operation (and build the column alias)
DISTINCT
GROUP BY
HAVING
ORDER BY
LIMIT and OFFSET
return the final result
```

The `MAX` function is called before the `GROUP BY`, which means the `MAX` will work across the whole table before the `GROUP BY` has even been performed, which from my understanding should result in the presence of a single maximum value **across the table** which should be **6000**. However, that's not what happens, the results I do see are confusingly in the right structure that I want:

```
max(Salary) DepartmentID
6000        1001
3100        2001
2750        3001
```

somehow the `MAX` function works after a `GROUP BY` but also before losing all the rows due to the `GROUP BY` dropping multiple group rows.

If I go ahead with this understanding it throws up more questions for me.

If a `GROUP BY` operation occurs **before** the `SELECT`, then the `GROUP BY` will remove all the rows for each `DepartmentID` and leave only a single row **randomly chosen**, which means by the time the `MAX` function in `SELECT` has a chance to even run it will only see one salary value which could be any value rather than the maximum for each Department.

What am I missing that is complicating my understanding?

Comment: "The MAX function is called before the GROUP BY"  Who did learn you that SQL is always interpreted from left to right?  Did anyone do so ? They are wrong...

Comment: The answer to your question is in the accepted answer of the question you linked to

Comment: Also, aggregation is done after `WHERE` and before `HAVING` -- otherwise `HAVING` would be redundant with `WHERE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing we need to understand when we evaluate a query is that there is a projection **before** the `group by` and there is a projection **after** the `group by`.

Before the `group by` we define what relation we are to group from. This may be an entire table, a projected table (the columns are different than initially defined), a filtered table (`where` clause and joins) or even an ad-hoc table (like (`select 1 as foo union select 2 as foo union select 3 as foo`)).

`GROUP BY` is the process of aggregating the results. This means that things like `MAX()` or `MIN()`, `AVG()` by default (notwithstanding indexes) is not evaluatable before the records that contribute to the result were not evaluated fully.

So, how would you evaluate the MAX value of something, for example:

(pseudo-code)

```
max <- -infinity
for r of rows do
    if max < r.yourfield then max <- r.yourfield
end for
```

and this is what happens in your case. `MAX(yourfield)` marks that for this field you need to find out what the maximum is for the result set. And if there was a `GROUP BY`, then the pseudo-code changes to something like this:

```
max <- -infinity
for r of rows do
    if max[group(row)] < r.yourfield then max[group(row)] <- r.yourfield
end for
```

So, the records are ungrouped and are being processed. As the groups are being built, the separate aggregated values are being built up separately.

Comment: This is perfect and really helps to give me confidence. Lot's more learning to do. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

[Aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html) like MAX (or SUM, MIN, COUNT etc) are applied to the sets created by the `GROUP BY` clause.

In your example the salaries for each department are divided into separate sets and the MAX-function is applied to each set giving the maximun salary for each department.